# Jump Encryption help? Code not making sense

Tags: java

Jump Encrypt: prompt the user to enter an integer (jump value) that is between 2 and the square root of the length of the current message, inclusive. Now imagine that we are going to write the current message in a table form, using the same number of rows as the jump value. The character order in the original message would be the order of the
first column, followed by the second column, etc. For example, with jump value of 5, the original message would be in table form:

```
T i e g   a
h s   i m g
i   o n e e
s t r a s .
  h i l s
```

To complete the encryption, display the encrypted message row by row, "Tieg ahs imgi oneestras. hils" for the above. Hint: this can be accomplished in one step with nested loops! No arrays or actual tables are required in the solution,

So I have attached the code that I have used down below, but it seems to be that I am off by one column when it comes to printing the message.

```
public static String jumpEncrypt(String message, int jumpValue) {
      String jencrypt = "";

      for (int i = 0; i < jumpValue; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < (jumpValue); j++) {
            jencrypt += message.charAt(i + j*jumpValue);
         }
      }

      return jencrypt;
   }
```

The expected output for the original message with a jumpValue of 5 should be "Tieg ahs imgi oneestras. hils" but I am getting an output of "Tieg hs imi onestras hils"

Comment: Did you try `<= jumpValue`?

Comment: it returns a StringIndexOutOfBounds error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating both `i` and `j` up to the `jumpValue`. That means that the maximum message you can encrypt is `jumpValue * jumpValue)` - or 25 in your case - characters, and your string is already longer (you can see that your "correct" matrix is 6x5).

So you need to iterator `j` not up to `jumpValue`, but up to the message length divided by `jumpValue` - and you need to round it up to the nearest whole number.

That also means that some of the characters in the last column of your matrix come from a position longer than the length of the input string, so you need to check for that.

The below code tackles both:

```
public static String jumpEncrypt(String message, int jumpValue) {
    String jencrypt = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < jumpValue; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (message.length() + jumpValue - 1) / jumpValue; j++) {
            int index = i + j * jumpValue;
            if (index < message.length()) {
                jencrypt += message.charAt(index);
            }
        }
    }

    return jencrypt;
}
```

Note that the expression `(message.length() + jumpValue - 1) / jumpValue` (which is `message.length() / jumpValue`, but rounded **up**) is constant throughout both loops, so for efficiency, it's better to extract it into a local variable before the loops, to avoid an unnecessary evaluation of the expression for every loop.

Answer (score 0):

So with this for loop code their is not much to go on but a simple fix might be
maybe j should be equal to one so message.charAt(i + j*jumpValue); it should not equal to 
 0 + 0*jumpValue) since that makes everything 0 and clears everything out to the basic.

so jencrypt = 0; no matter what its initial value was.

so maybe jumpValue - 1 for int i = 0;

Trying doing the math portion of the floor loop and see why its not adding up correctly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jumpValue - 1; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < (jumpValue); j++) {
        jencrypt += message.charAt(i + j*jumpValue);
     }
  }

  return jencrypt;
```

I am not completely sure if I am right but I did my best to understand I am pretty new still to coding! :)

Comment: Hi so this basically returns the same message that I was getting, but does not iterate through all of the rows, and cuts the message short, while still getting the problem I was earlier. Thank you so much though!

Comment: Did you try doing plus 1 instead since it seems that the program was already ending short to begin with

Comment: Actually instead of using jumpValue twice in each for loop have you tried replacing one them with message.length;?

Comment: so plus 1 returns "Tieg hs imi onestras hilsieg a" which is closer in that it isnt leaving out the "a" but the return we should get is "Tieg ahs imgi oneestras. hils"

Comment: I have not, which one would I replace with message.length()?

Comment: I want to say the problem seems to either be the forloop vaule with jumpValue I think you might need to replace one of those with the message.length; Or it could be the message.CharAt(i + j*JumpValue); this math might be off a little bit and may be causing the code to fall out of order.

Comment: I would replace the second one that in ()

Comment: so the other thing is that when I changed my code to:

Comment: public static String jumpEncrypt(String message, int jumpValue) {
      String jencrypt = "";
      int messageLength = message.length();
      for (int i = 0; i < jumpValue; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j <= (jumpValue); j++) {
            if ((i + (j*jumpValue)) >= messageLength){
               jencrypt += "";
            }
            else {
               jencrypt += message.charAt(i + j*jumpValue);
            }
         }
      }
        
      return jencrypt;
   }

Comment: it worked if the jumpValue was equal to 5, but if it was equal to anything less than 5, it returns a string that is completely wrong

Comment: replacing it to message.length() gives an error message

Answer (score 0):

If I use `for (int j = 0; j <= (jumpValue); j++)`, and make no other changes, it works for me.

Comment: would you mind explaining why or showing me what you did in the first for loop?